# JavaScript / jQuery animate error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a function here that toggles opening/closing a div:

```
function searchAnimate(goTo) {
    if (goTo == "open") {
        $("#searchdiv").animate({
            bottom: 2,
            right: 0
        }, 1500);
        document.getElementById("openclosearrow").innerHTML = "<div onclick='searchAnimate('close')' id='openclosearrow'>&harr;</div>";
    }
    if (goTo == "close") {
        $("#searchdiv").animate({
            bottom: -45,
            right: -218
        }, 1500);
        document.getElementById("openclosearrow").innerHTML = "<div onclick='searchAnimate('open')' id='openclosearrow'>&harr;</div>";
    }
}
```

The error is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**. I have tried to fix it many ways, but I guess my eyes are just not working today... Can anyone help? Thx!

P.S. If it helps, I am using Chrome.

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div onclick="searchAnimate('close')" id="openclosearrow">&harr;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this and the mixing of DOM and jQuery is a bad idea, pick one way so it is standard.

One issue with your code is the quotes are wrong, they need to be escaped

```
"<div onclick=\"searchAnimate('open')\" id='openclosearrow'>&harr;</div>"
```

The problem here is you are replacing the innerHTML of an element with the same code so it would look like this after the first replace

```
<div onclick="searchAnimate('close')" id="openclosearrow"><div onclick="searchAnimate('close')" id="openclosearrow">&harr;</div></div>
```

I doubt that is what you want.

What you should do is replace the event handler.

```
$("#openclosearrow").off("click").on("click",function(){ searchAnimate('open') });
```

Better yet is not to replace click handler but to detect the state.

```
function searchAnimate() {
    var stateSettings,
        newState,
        elem = $("#searchdiv");
    if (elem.data("state")==="open") {
        newState = "close";
        stateSettings = {
            bottom: 2,
            right: 0
        };
    } else {
        newState = "open";
        stateSettings = {
            bottom: -45,
            right: -218
        }
    }
    elem.data("state",newState).animate(stateSettings, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are totally right: .innerHTML changes INSIDE the div... DUMB DUMB DUMB... I dunno what happened. I have used .innerHTML hundreds of times... What makes today different? Anyways, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML for the elements you're adding has quotes within quotes.

Also, it looks like you're trying to replace an element by setting its `innerHTML`.  That also won't work.

What you need is just *one* handler on that element, and some sort of marker to indicate what state it's in. The handler can use that to know whether a click should open or close.

Maybe something like this:

```
<div id='openclosearrow' class='open'>&harr;</div>
```

Then, in the JavaScript:

```
$('#openclosearrow').click(function() {
  var arrow = this, $arrow = $(arrow),
    animations = {
      open: { bottom: 2, right: 0 },
      close: { bottom: -45, right: -218 }
    };

  $('#searchdiv').animate(animations[ $arrow.is('.open') ? 'close' : 'open' ], 1500);
  $arrow.toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: You'll have to escape the inner quotes with a prepended \ if the inner quotes are the same as the outer quotes in Javascript

Comment: Strange mix of jQuery and native JS, too. To replace an element, jQuery makes this facile via `.replaceWith()`